# Does every UIView need a controller, or can a controller control several views?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Does every UIView need a controller, or can a controller manage several views? If a controller can manage multiple views, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

no, not every view needs it's own ViewController: If you just create your own view which contains labels, textfields, etc then your ViewController will control your view **and** the instances of textfields ...

But in most cases it is useful to create for every new created view its own viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller does exactly what it says: control views.

A view is simply something that can render itself on screen, it doesn't know anything about behavior.

Not every view has a view controller, far from it. Most views are subviews to other views, which are in turn controlled by the parent view controller.

For the most part, only one view controller is used at a time.